# ViewModel Doesn't cache data for RecyclerView and saving ListState doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-architecture-components

## **I want the RecyclerView to retain it's position on device rotations.**

I have 4 classes (2 Activities and 2 ViewModels) which are called [MainActivity](https://github.com/jihadnaji/Popular-Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/popularmovies/ui/MainActivity.java), [FavouritesActivity](https://github.com/jihadnaji/Popular-Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/popularmovies/ui/FavouritesActivity.java). PLUS [MainViewModel](https://github.com/jihadnaji/Popular-Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/popularmovies/viewmodel/MainViewModel.java), [FavouritesViewModel](https://github.com/jihadnaji/Popular-Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/popularmovies/viewmodel/FavouritesViewModel.java) which extends [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel). All things with FavouriteAvtivity and FavouriteViewModel works perfectly fine. Meanwhile, the other two are implemented the same way but when I rotate the device my List's scroll position resets, and I have literally tried everything I found regarding saving the list state in onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

Here's my application repo on GitHub: [**PopularMovies**](https://github.com/jihadnaji/Popular-Movies)

Comment: Build failed Could not get unknown property 'MyMovieDbApiKey' , you can provide any dummy key to make it build properly.

Comment: You said that FavouriteAvtivity and FavouriteViewModel works perfectly fine, for me FavouriteAvtivity is blank.

Comment: You have to favourite some movies then the movies will show there,
I haven't provided a layout for when the activity is blank. Sorry for misconception.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma did it work for you?

Comment: No didn't find anything wrong, didn't find the root cause. Will look today in sometime again, meanwhile if you find the cause please drop comment.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you so much sir. Really appreciated. Absolutely will let you know as soon as I find something out.

Comment: I think have found the root cause now , will comment once I have proper fix.

Comment: Added the fix in answer, please review and verify the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue cause why it's happening for MainActivity only even though implementations are same. The issue is with your layout **movie_list_item**, you have to specify constant height otherwise layout gets remeasure and list scrolled up on device rotate. to prevent that use the below modified layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/iv_movie_thumbnail"
       android:layout_width="184dp"
       android:layout_height="180dp" // don't use wrap_content, can use any height you want but make it that fix
       android:contentDescription="@string/movie_thumbnail"/>
```

Comment: Yasss, it did work. THANK you so much. This bug was driveing me nuts to be honest.

Comment: @JihadNaji glad to help you! Thank you !!